# SQL Query for fetching 5 rows from one column?

Tags: mysql

SQL query for fetching five rows/data from one column?

Comment: Read about LIMIT in the select statement. Select .... LIMIT 0,5

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT columnName FROM Table LIMIT 5
```

or

```
SELECT columnName FROM Table WHERE anotherColumn = somevalue LIMIT 5
```

Or

```
SELECT columnName FROM Table WHERE anotherColumn = somevalue ORDER BY columnName1 asc LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL SERVER

SELECT TOP 5 ColumnName FROM TableName;

- will return 5 records, but you won't know which ones unless the TableName is indexed by ColumnName or you sort by ColumnName
- will return the requested number of rows if the table has as many or more rows than requested.

Answer (score 0):

I think ORDER BY plays an important role in finalizing the 5 records

```
SELECT columnName FROM Table order by ID desc LIMIT 5
```